# exception while using ksoap2 library for android

Tags: android, ksoap2

I'm using Ksoap2 version 2.5.4 in my maven enabled android Project. Any reference to the Ksoap specific classes is throwing this exception

```
04-18 20:35:15.429: ERROR/dalvikvm(626): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.rare.Main.fetchSoapResponse
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at com.rare.Main.fetchSoapResponse(Main.java:57)
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at com.rare.Main.onCreate(Main.java:23)
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-18 20:35:15.662: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(626):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the line of code causing this is

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
```

Couldn't find any help related to this on SO or other forums. This seems pretty straight forward. Can any one tell me whats missing and how I can make android use the library at run time.

Comment: Have you downloaded the [`...-jar-with-dependencies.jar`](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.5.4/) version? Have you added to the build path the external jar?

Comment: if i add the external library i get this error message 'Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1'

Comment: the steps that worked for me are: right click on project -> build path -> add external archives.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- In your build path clear all libraries (jar files).
- In project's main directory create a folder and named it "libs" (not
  "lib").
- Now Eclipse ADT Plugin will add your jar files to build path.
- Clean & Build your project if necessary.
- Happy coding

Comment: You missed final step :) Restarting eclipse. Then worked fine http://stackoverflow.com/a/9878130/413032

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.I have added ZIP file instead of jar file to external library, you need to add only the JAR file.